# I have Some issue in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I have Some issue in  .htaccess file.I have hosted my index page to webserver. I don't know  what I did wrong in the .htaccess file.After adding code in .htaccess file still my url is not friendly.It is showing http://rang.comli.com/servicecnt It should be http://rang.comli.com/servicecnt/service_id/5

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Second mod_rewrite example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            welcome index page. Index page is loaded
            <a  href="http://rang.comli.com/servicecnt.php?service_id=5">Done with php my admin</a>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /public_html/index.php to /dir/index
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /public_html/index to /dir/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^service_id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^servicecnt\.php$ /servicecnt.php/%1? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: can any one help me?.htaccess is annoying

Comment: can any one hepl me?

Comment: Patience is a good thing. Learn how to acquire it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+servicecnt\.php\?service_id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ servicecnt/service_id/%1? [R=302,L]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /public_html/index.php to /dir/index
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^servicecnt/service_id/(\d+)/?$ servicecnt.php?service_id=$1 [QSA,L]

## To internally redirect /public_html/index to /dir/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: I want to know how did u write the rewritecond i think you have added RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+servicecnt\.php\?service_id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ servicecnt/service_id/%1? [R=302,L].I you don't mind can you explain me? these line?

Comment: Did it work in your testing? I used `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable.  `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Comment: yes it is working you can see the link http://rang.comli.com/ after click done with Done with php my admin. what does \s mean?is it relevant to sercicecnt.php?service_id or query string or apache?

Comment: `\s` matches a whitespace. Not related with `sercicecnt.php`

Comment: for example if i want to make another friendly link:shall i want to do the same procedure? 
 <a  href="http://rang.comli.com/tuition.php?tuition_id=5">Tuition</a>
  <a  href="http://rang.comli.com/Technology.php?technology_id=5">Technology</a>

 <a  href="http://rang.comli.com/exam.php?exam_id=5">Exam</a>

Comment: Yes you can write similar rules for the new URL. Try it out and let me know if it dissent work for some reason.

Comment: Yes it is working man you can check with the link http://rang.comli.com/ after click tuition. for my clarification service_id is the query string/(\d) for integer.start with ^condition?$ with end.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is not to redirect the old url, but to let php generate the pretty url in the first place. Every time an user clicks on your link, the server needs to redirect the user, which is very inefficient. If the user would click the new url instead, you only have to internally rewrite it. You can use the following rule to rewrite it back:

```
RewriteRule ^servicecnt/service_id/([^/]+)/?$ servicecnt.php?service_id=$1 [L]
```