# How do I use get method in friendly url.

Tags: .htaccess

my url is:http://rang.comli.com/servicecnt/service_id/5. 
Using .htaccess file,I have created the friendly url.I want to retrieve the url values by using $_GET method.So far I have done in php like this,but I want to know how to get by using $_GET method and assign to variable.

```
<?php
    $htp=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $htp_arr=explode("/",$htp);
    echo $htp;
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($htp_arr)."<br/>";
    echo "ID=".$htp_arr[3]."<br/>";
    echo "Name=".$htp_arr[2]."<br/>";
    echo "Name2=".$htp_arr[1]."<br/>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using .htaccess [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884083/i-have-some-issue-in-htaccess-file) then just use:

```
$serviceId = $_GET['service_id'];
```

For tution URI add this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^tution/tution_id/(\d+)/?$ tution.php?tution_id==$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I use this line to avoid .php extension is this correct
# To externally redirect /public_html/index.php to /dir/index
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L] because in my index page i am giving my achor tag like this in index page <a  href="http://rang.comli.com/tuition.php?tuition_id=5">Tuition</a>
 <a  href="http://rang.comli.com/Technology.php?technology_id=5">Technology</a>.because i am going to make the menu dynamic it falls in above way.shall i need to give this code or what we done yesterday is enough

Comment: That earlier rules is for `/servicecnt.php?service_id=` URI. You need a similar rule for `/tution.php?tution_id=` URI

Comment: ok I understood that one you helped me lot in that.I am asking this line ## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /public_html/index.php to /dir/index
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

Comment: Yes this rule looks fine for that.

Comment: Great.In menu I am giving this <a  href="http://rang.comli.com/kodiasha.php?k=2">click to view</a><br/><br/>
 <a  href="http://rang.comli.com/servicecnt.php?service_id=5">Done with php my admin</a> is it necessary to give servicecnt.php or servicecnt is enough, clarify my doubt. this is my final query

Comment: That rule won't affect `http://rang.comli.com/kodiasha.php?k=2` URL so you can keep using this.